# DOMXPath Match text

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

Code sample:

```html
$html = <<<END
  <tr>
    <td>Text-1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Blah 1</td>
    <td>Blah 2</td>
    <td>Blah 3</td>
    <td>Blah 4</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Text-2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Blah 1</td>
    <td>Blah 2</td>
    <td>Blah 3</td>
    <td>Blah 4</td>
  </tr>
END;

$dom = new DOMDocument(); 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadhtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

   // Grab the text
$nodes = $xpath->query('//td[contains(text(), "Text-2")]|//td[contains(text(), "Blah 1")]/following-sibling::td');

echo $nodes->item(0)->textContent;
```

I'm trying to grab Blah 2 under Text-2, the problem is that's grabbing Blah 2 under Text-1

Comment: You're not supposed to add the answer inside your question, please post a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, find the `<tr>` that has a `<td>` child with `"Text-2"`, then traverse down the next sibling until you find a `<td>` that has `"Blah 1"`. The answer is the next sibling of that.

```
//tr[contains(td/text(), "Text-2")]/following-sibling::tr/td[contains(text(), "Blah 1")]/following-sibling::td'
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```html
//*[text()='Text-2']/following::td[text()='Blah 1']/following-sibling::td
```